# Species identification. Is this a leech?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, invertebrates

[image]

The pictured creature, shown at the bottom of a glass, was attached to a friend’s child after he was swimming in the Ottawa River today. It stretches out to roughly an inch in length but in this “resting pose” was around half that length. Below is a shot of the mark left behind:

[image]

It looks like a leech to me, but I thought I’d ask the Internet.

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do better next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is a leech. It appears to be a species in the family [Glossiphoniidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossiphoniidae), or the **freshwater jawless leeches**. This family of leeches is relatively flattened with a poorly defined anterior sucker.

According to [The Canadian Encyclopedia](https://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/leech), there are about 45 species of leeches found in or around Canada.

[Langer *et al.* (2018)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d0a8/870c5800a5e4a8e0d35a3e1028d2487ee5fa.pdf)<sup>1</sup> provide a more limited selection of Glossiphoniidae leeches they ascribed to Ontario. Of the ones they list, yours most looks like a specimen from the genus *Placobdella*.

See, for example, this image of *Placobdella phalera* from [de Carle *et al.* (2017)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sebastian_Kvist/publication/317949197_Phylogenetic_analysis_of_Placobdella_Hirudinea_Rhynchobdellida_Glossiphoniidae_with_consideration_of_COI_variation/links/595f70ea0f7e9b8194dc61ee/Phylogenetic-analysis-of-Placobdella-Hirudinea-Rhynchobdellida-Glossiphoniidae-with-consideration-of-COI-variation.pdf)<sup>2</sup> found in Ontario, Canada:

[image]

<sup>Source: Figure 1, [de Carle *et al.* (2017)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sebastian_Kvist/publication/317949197_Phylogenetic_analysis_of_Placobdella_Hirudinea_Rhynchobdellida_Glossiphoniidae_with_consideration_of_COI_variation/links/595f70ea0f7e9b8194dc61ee/Phylogenetic-analysis-of-Placobdella-Hirudinea-Rhynchobdellida-Glossiphoniidae-with-consideration-of-COI-variation.pdf)</sup>

---

1  <sup>Langer, S.V., Vezsenyi, K.A., De Carle, D., Beresford, D.V. and Kvist, S., 2017. Leeches (Annelida: Hirudinea) from the far north of Ontario: distribution, diversity, and diagnostics. *Canadian Journal of Zoology*, 96(2), pp.141-152.</sup>

2  <sup>de Carle, D., Oceguera-Figueroa, A., Tessler, M., Siddall, M.E. and Kvist, S., 2017. Phylogenetic analysis of Placobdella (Hirudinea: Rhynchobdellida: Glossiphoniidae) with consideration of COI variation. Molecular phylogenetics and evolution, 114, pp.234-248.</sup>